# Get transaction input ring members as public keys

Tags: monerod, rpc

How can I get transaction ring members using the `monerod` RPC methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First call [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) then translate the key_offsets and call [get_outs](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_outs).

For example, let's decode the ring members for the second input of [this tx](https://xmrchain.net/tx/329c12515493165e5580cf5541d429ca3f59d7ac949ba918c0f84af9450f13a8):

```
curl -sd '{"txs_hashes":["329c12515493165e5580cf5541d429ca3f59d7ac949ba918c0f84af9450f13a8"],\
  "decode_as_json":true}' http://localhost:18081/get_transactions
```

You can extract the `key_offsets` from [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions):

```
key_offsets: [ 18763375, 1355999, 49546, 5266, 1370, 14093, 15945, 6499, 3974, 636, 1119]
```

Which get translated to:

```
18763375, 20119374, 20168920, 20174186, 20175556, 20189649, 20205594, 20212093, 20216067, 20216703, 20217822
```

(each is the sum of the previous offsets)

Then call [get_outs](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_outs):

```
curl -sd '{"outputs":[{"index":18763375},\
  {"index":20119374},{"index":20168920},\
  {"index":20174186},{"index":20175556},\
  {"index":20189649},{"index":20205594},\
  {"index":20212093},{"index":20216067},\
  {"index":20216703},{"index":20217822}]}' http://localhost:18081/get_outs
```

Which returns the public keys:

```
{
  "credits": 0,
  "outs": [{
    "height": 2136433,
    "key": "fa78cea6203fe2093f8227bc70178752e6f980e74f97151f20e7a758c2993b4e",
    "mask": "0465b14419742fddd320c44165e8f62dfcbf7521baf35f08c8c11de0a669f651",
    "txid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "unlocked": true
  },{
    "height": 2171860,
    "key": "eb0ff1ffc50228a7858e45d2414030d3b76bc7a511f9148c67b07778b9b0c536",
    "mask": "48a1dfd783515eaa151482a8ec05b8cc544e89dd42ea7a238fd4fe757d437b7d",
    "txid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "unlocked": true
  }, etc etc {
    "height": 2173803,
    "key": "29e072904dda63d2837753ab56f9079e60d74b68ce8d3af4a3c9bd0338f7427a",
    "mask": "456d63570d1fd3ca38ba712e6f84cd20d1344d59b46077663dce6b1c4f383c43",
    "txid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "unlocked": true
  }],
  "status": "OK",
  "top_hash": "",
  "untrusted": false
}
```